# Unable to get Tomcat Security constraints working for conf\web.xml

Tags: security, tomcat, constraints, web.xml

I have a Tomcat webapp deployed that is using security constraints at the WEB-INF level (webapps\app1\WEB-INF\web.xml). So it works on well:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>app1</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

It just directs users to HTTPS if they try to go through HTTP. My issue is that I can not get it to work at the conf level. (conf/web.xml)

Why wouldn't it work at that level if it works just fine in webapps?